# How to modify `Alt` + `Tab` behaviour in Windows 10 to behave like it used to?

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

This is a small thing, but it gets me so many times a day that I want to find a resolution. Back in the good 'ol days, the command `Alt` + `Tab` in windows simple switched between the current window and the window last viewed. Lets call it behaviour 1 and it what I'm trying to get back to. These days however, after three cycles of pressing `Alt` + `Tab`, Windows will switch to a different window, usually the third in the "z-stack" of windows. Lets call this behaviour 2. So my question is, how can I get Windows 10 to use behaviour 1 and not behaviour 2.

I am aware of the `Multitasking` setting which looks like this:
[image]

There is no setting which controls the "three press" rule.

Comment: “There is no setting which controls the "three press" rule.” – That’s because it doesn’t exist. I cannot observe the behavior you describe on my machine. Are you sure it’s not another window stealing focus?

Comment: It most definitely *does exist because its been the source of annoyance for me for a long time =] Strange that you cannot reproduce the behaviour 2 though. Could a third party perhaps share the `Alt` + `Tab` behaviour on their system? Mine can't be the *only one, surely.

Comment: Kindly check if the methods in this article was helpful to you: [Alt Tab Not Working in Windows 10](https://windowsreport.com/alt-tab-not-working-windows-8/)

Comment: Alt + Tab on my Windows 10 machine goes from the app I'm currently using, to the last one used. When I press it again, it goes back to the previous app, so essentially it is cycling through the two most recently used apps.